# C# Evento ao pressionar botão, não ao clicar

Tags: c#

Eu preciso executar uma função exatamente ao pressionar o botão.

Pela função comum `Botao1_Click` ele só executa quando você solta o *click*, ou seja, se vc clica e segura um tempinho pressionado ele não executa. Se mantém 2 segundos pressionando, a função também não executa; ela só é chamada depois que vc solta o *click*.

```
private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ minha_funcao(); }
```

Comment: Resolvido. A opção correta é acionar o evento mouseDown.

Answer (score -1):

Bom dia.

Isso é usando outro evento na lista de eventos lá vc encontra vários outros eventos além do evento click. Essa dificuldade sua talvez se deve ao fato que usa a criação do método dando dois clicks no controle.

Na área de eventos escolha o evento desejado e programe a função desejada.

Comment: Considere colocar esse tipo de texto como comentário.

Comment: Sim, sim, mouseDown está na lista de eventos.... isso mesmo....